# Universal Image Loader portrait/ landscape issue Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the Universal Image Loader library to load and show an image from the gallery. My problem is that the image is not being shown properly. No matter what photo I choose they are all displayed in landscape mode.I have to turn them if I want portrait. I saw that he has something that should render them automatically based on size https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/commit/8ba3407c3b781fbc714377e8b3845242741468d8. Is that facility integrated automatically in the loader or do I have to implement it somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a method in display options, if you don't..

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
...
        .considerExifParams(true)
...
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks.. I had that in my options, but it seems like the picture was actually landscape. No idea how I managed to take a landscape selfie. It works now. Thank you .